# Display the index of a List<> item

Tags: c#

I am adding new items to the list and the list box simultaneously. I also want to make sure that whenever it is added to the list it will display its index. Its probably easy to do but I'm struggling and can't find any answer to this.

This is the closest I got but it still give me error:

> Cannot convert from string to ListProgram.Animal

This is the code:

```
 animals.Add(new Animal()
 {
     Name = txtName.Text.ToString(),
     Specie = txtSpecie.Text.ToString()
 });

 lstQuizList.Items.Add(animals.IndexOf(txtName.Text));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's a list of Animal objects not a list of animal names

Comment: Why are you trying to add indexes to a list, and why are you trying to find an animal name (string) in a list of `Animals`?

Comment: Why are you searching the list for the item _you just added_? That item's index is always going to be `animals.Count - 1`. See marked duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lstQuizList.Items.Add(animals.FindIndex(a => a.Name == txtName.Text));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. It dosen't work, it's not finding the a => a.Name

Comment: Ahh now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Overkill. Use this: lstQuizList.Items.Add(animals.Count - 1);